# Ajax call doesn't wait the variable refreshing

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

I've built an ajax call which is triggered every time the select changes :

```js
$('select[name="resource"]').on('change', function() {
   $.ajax({
      type: 'GET',
      url: '/affaires/jours/'+$(e.relatedTarget).data('affaire-id')+'/'+$(this).val(),
      success: function (data) {
         console.log(data);
      },
      error: function(data) {
      }
   }).done(function(data) {
     data.jour_proposition !== null ? $('input[name="days_prop"]').val(data.jour_proposition + " jours") : $('input[name="days_prop"]').val("0 jours")
     data.jour_realisation !== null ? $('input[name="days_rea"]').val(data.jour_realisation + " jours") : $('input[name="days_rea"]').val("0 jours")
   });
})
```

The 2 problematic variables are `$e(relatedTarget).data('affaire-id')` and `$(this).val()`, which are injected into the url. I've the feeling that they don't refresh before the ajax call. So the first call after the page refreshes works well but if I rerun the call for another select, it calls ajax 2 times. First with the old variables, then with the good variables :

[image: js console errors]

To user who doesn't look into the javascript console error, no change because the right url is called after few milliseconds but I want to remove this error if possible.

I tried to wrap these `$e(relatedTarget).data('affaire-id')` and `$(this).val()` into variables, with the if condition around the ajax call `if($foo !== null && $bar !== null) { ajax call }`, and reinitialize variables to `null` in the `done` of the call but without success.

Comment: Is your on-change event listener wrapped within other code? Could it be creating multiple listeners? That's the only thing I can think of that will trigger your on-change listeners twice. Also, I don't see where you are getting `e` for your `e.relatedTarget`.

Comment: Your server responds with error 500 every time, what's up with that?

Comment: The "change" event happens *after* a form field value has changed, so it can't be a simple timing issue. But maybe you have other code that changes the form field values? Programmatic changes to form field values don't trigger the "change" event. Check your event dependencies.

Comment: Apart from that, you refer to `e.relatedTarget` but your event handler does not even define `e`.